# To fill a collection from sql statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table which holds images of children. Now I want to read all the image URL of a particular child with his/her Child_ID. The problem is that I don't know how to fill the collection from the reader. Below you can find the code I am using;

```
private void Bindlist()
{
    string id = Request.QueryString["ID"];

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetChildImages", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChildID", id));

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                  var list = new Collection<MyImage> 
                   {
                   };


                }
            }
        } catch (Exception)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Error.htm", false);
        }

    }

    Repeater1.DataSource = array; 
    Repeater1.DataBind(); 
}

 public class MyImage
 {

     public string ImageSRC { get; set; }
     public string ThumbImageSRC { get; set; }

 }
```

Comment: have you tried to search or view documentation of [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)? The documentation is with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out with following piece of code:

```
 private void Bindlist()
 {
string id = Request.QueryString["ID"];
List<MyImage> listImage=new List<MyImage>();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetChildImages", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChildID", id));

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    MyImage image=new MyImage();
                    image.ImageSRC=reader.GetString(0);
                    image.ThumbImageSRC=reader.GetString(1);
                    listImage.Add(image);

                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Error.htm", false);
    }

}

Repeater1.DataSource = listImage; 
Repeater1.DataBind(); 
}

public class MyImage
{

 public string ImageSRC { get; set; }
 public string ThumbImageSRC { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) method of the reader:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
  var list = new Collection<MyImage>();
  while(reader.Read())
  {
    // create new `MyImage` from reader - you now have access to the columns
    // guessing at names of the columns:
    list.Add(new MyImage { ImageSRC = (string)reader["URL"], 
                           ThumbImageSRC = (string)reader["URL_Small"]  });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        MyImage i = new MyImage();
        i.YourPropery1 = (string) reader["Column1"];
        i.YourPropery2 = (int) reader["Column2"];
        ...
        list.add(i);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    while(reader.read())
    {
      var list = new Collection<MyImage> 
       {
          ImageSRC =reader.GetString(columnIndex),
          ThumbImageSRC=reader.GetString(columnIndex)
        };
     }
```